# Logout Display alert xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been trying to allow a user to confirm logout by using DisplayAlert. If they click "No" it should remain in their profile page else they should be redirected back to the login page. I haven't managed to get this done, if I click Yes or No, both options remain in the profile page

```
public async void LogoutBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var answer = await DisplayAlert("Exit", "Do you wan't to exit the App?", "Yes", "No");
    if(answer.Equals("Yes"))
    {
        Settings.FirstName = string.Empty;
        Settings.LastName = string.Empty;
        Settings.Email = string.Empty;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
    }
    else
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new Profile();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DisplayAlert` returns a boolean (`true` / `false`):

```
var answer = await DisplayAlert("Exit", "Do you wan't to exit the App?", "Yes", "No");
if (answer)
{
    // User choose Yes
}
else
{
    // User choose No
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups it returns a string.

Comment: @EvZ It returns a `Task<bool>`

Comment: you are right https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayAlert/p/System.String/System.String/System.String/System.String/ I got confused with DisplayActionSheet

Answer (score 0):

As SushiHangover point out `DisplayAlert` returns a `bool`. You should replace it with `DisplayActionSheet` or stay with it and correct the if.

Your `else` clause seems to be incorrect.
If the user choose `No` you should do nothing. Why do you assign a new Profile to the MainPage?

Beside that, it seems that you have problems with navigation in general. Looking at your code, logout will push a page on a top of the executing page. Seems a bit weird. I would recommend to get familiar wit the `Navigation` topic firs of all:
[Official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/)
There is a [free course on Xamarin University on Navigation](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-forms-navigation-patterns-xam205/)

Comment: I removed the else clause, the app still remains on Profile instead of logging out when I click Yes

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check if you hit the Navigation part inside the if.